# Select just first value under grandparent while using apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt

**xml:**

```
<Item>
  <ItemGroup groupId="A">
    <ItemEntry>
      <CustomerRef>A123456</CustomerRef> <!-- need to select just this / first element value -->
    </ItemEntry>
    <ItemEntry>
      <CustomerRef>A123456</CustomerRef>
    </ItemEntry>
    <ItemEntry>
      <CustomerRef>A123456</CustomerRef>
    </ItemEntry>
  </ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup groupId="B">
  <ItemEntry>
    <CustomerRef>B123456</CustomerRef> <!-- need to select just this / first element value -->
  </ItemEntry>
  <ItemEntry>
    <CustomerRef>B123456</CustomerRef>
  </ItemEntry>
</ItemGroup>
</Item>
```

**xsl:**

```
<xsl:template match="ItemGroup" mode="PREMISE">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./@groupId" />
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <xsl:value-of select="./ItemEntry/CustomerRef"></xsl:value-of>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
</xsl:template>
```

**Result:**
Currently, the `CustomerRef` is printed as many times as it appears in the grandparent node `ItemGroup`

Comment: Hi @j-olufsen, I don't get the question/problem. Maybe you can explain it more thoroughly and/or add the output xml that you need.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<xsl:template match="ItemGroup" mode="PREMISE">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./@groupId" />
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <xsl:value-of select="./ItemEntry[1]/CustomerRef"></xsl:value-of>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice. Delete one of the duplicate questions. Also, you should attribute the person that [wrote this correct answer in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892702/how-to-select-value-of-the-first-element-value-and-skip-the-rest-under-one-grand#comment105913111_59892702).